# Script to get File Creation and Last Access Date and time (In Solaris 5.10)

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I want to run a script to acquire file details with file creation date (with time) and last access date (with time). I want to run the script in a directory and want the script to show the details of all files in that directory as well in subdirectories. Here is the script which I tried, but I am not able to get  subdirectory files.

```
#! /bin/zsh - 
zmodload zsh/stat for f (*(DN)) { 
    stat -LH s -F %F -- $f && 
    printf '%-58s %s %s\n' $f $s[mtime] $s[atime]
}
```

- OS: Solaris 5.10
- FileSystem: VFS

Comment: What did you tried ? Can you share your actual script ? Unix&Linux isn't "do my job for free" site ... we are here to help you on the base of your current work and achievement.

Comment: Hey Binarym, I certainly understand your concern!! Here is the script which I tried. 
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (*(DN)) {
  stat -LH s -F %F -- $f &&
    printf '%-58s %s %s\n' $f $s[mtime] $s[atime]
}

Comment: @Akki the right place to show your existing effort is [in the question, by editing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/315334).  You might also mention the filesystem(s) you're on, in case they offer varying levels of support in a file's ctime and atime.

Comment: Can someone please help with this?